# How to get group id when name is selected

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want a user to select group name from drop down list, then I want to take id of selected group and save it in database. The problem here when I select group name, the returned id became zero rather than group id?

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <select id="sel_group" name="groups"  class="bs-select form-control input-medium">
    <option value="@group_id">Select Group....</option></select>                            
</div>
```

Code to save data:

```
 public int Create(User user, int userId)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Global.Config.ConnStr))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spp_txn_user_ins", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@username", user.userName.Trim()));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@fullname", user.fullname));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@pwd", user.pwd));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@email", user.email.Trim()));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@mobile", user.mobile.Trim()));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@designation", user.designation));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@userid", user.createUser));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@group_id", user.group_id));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@add_content", user.add_content == null ? dbNull : (int)user.add_content));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@edit_content", user.edit_content == null ? dbNull : (int)user.edit_content));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@delete_content", user.delete_content == null ? dbNull : (int)user.delete_content));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@manage_user", user.manage_user == null ? dbNull : (int)user.manage_user));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@view_log", user.view_log == null ? dbNull : (int)user.view_log));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@result", 0)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

            return int.Parse(cmd.Parameters["@result"].Value.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Jquery :

```
//append data in dropdownlist
$(document).ready(function () {
    var url_list = "api/usergroup/getdata";
    $.getJSON(url_list)
    .done(function (data) {

        $.each(data, function (index, obj) {
            $("#sel_group").append("<option value='" + obj.id + "'>" + obj.name + "</option>")
            console.log(obj.name);
        })
    });
});
```

Could anyone tell me how to get id of selected group name from drop down list?

Comment: How do you set the `user.group_id`?

Comment: I added it to User class ` public int group_id { get; set; }`

Comment: Sure, but I'm asking how you populate it. Something like `user.group_id = ...`

Comment: i populate it using Jquery..i will update question with jquery code

Comment: Add the c# code to the question please where you set the properties of the user object that you try to save to the db. :)

Comment: updated. see the question

Comment: The group_id is zero probably because that is the initial value of Integer. So the problem is that you don't set it correctly. This has nothing to do with the db insert function, the problematic part probably the one where you create the user object and set its properties.

Answer (score 0):

in jquery you can do it like that:

```
var grp_val=$.("#sel_group").val();
```

you can get the selected value,then,post or get the value to you function